Add extra workspaces on Hyprland
I've been configuring Hyprland for my Debian Sid laptop for a few days and I haven't been able to add additional workspaces like I did on BSPWM and i3wm. I usually have at least 6 extra workspaces assigned to Super + F1 through F6. I'm using the original configuration and adding features from the dotfiles featured in hyprland.org and Reddit.
I read the official Hyprland documentation looking for the workspace declaration statement that I should use in my hyprland.conf but haven't been able to find it so far. I also read GitHub issues and Reddit posts without any success so far.

sorry if too late to the conversation.
In short - Hyprland doesn't keep a workspace active by default if the space is empty. You can however change that by using persistent:[b] ([b] being the workspace number you want to keep) in your hyprland.conf file.
you can have a look at all the config samples
